# redshift partition external table by part of a string

Tags: amazon-redshift, partitioning, external-tables

I haven't seen an answer after days of searching - so here goes

I have an Athena database with a table foo. Adding it to Redshift I use this command:

```
create external schema athena_schema from data catalog 
database 'my-catalog-db' 
iam_role '...role/my_redshift_role';
```

my table foo has 45 fields and one of them is a timestamp stored as a string. I want to partition the data in the table by JUST the date portion of the string.

The string looks like '2021/02/09 20:10:09:001', lets call it mydate

So I've tried this:

```
alter table athena_schema.foo
partition(left(mydate, 10) = '2021/02/09')
location 's3://my s3 location/foo_2021_02_09/';
```

And Redshift doesn't like the substring commands on an existing field. I've tried them.
Any ideas?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a partition in a Redshift Spectrum (and Athena) external table the partition column becomes a *separate* column in your table. That means that you cannot map a partition onto a column that *also* exists in the table data file.

In the example DDL from ["Partitioning Redshift Spectrum external tables"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-tables.html#c-spectrum-external-tables-partitioning) you can see that the partition column `saledate` is added as another column in the table.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.sales_part (
      salesid     INTEGER
    , listid      INTEGER
    , sellerid    INTEGER
    , buyerid     INTEGER
    , eventid     INTEGER
    , dateid      SMALLINT
    , qtysold     SMALLINT
    , pricepaid   DECIMAL(8,2)
    , commission  DECIMAL(8,2)
    , saletime    TIMESTAMP               )
PARTITIONED BY (saledate CHAR(10))
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/spectrum/sales_partition/'
TABLE PROPERTIES ('numRows'='172000');

--Add partitions
ALTER TABLE spectrum.sales_part ADD
PARTITION (saledate='2008-01') LOCATION 's3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/spectrum/sales_partition/saledate=2008-01/'
PARTITION (saledate='2008-02') LOCATION 's3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/spectrum/sales_partition/saledate=2008-02/'
PARTITION (saledate='2008-03') LOCATION 's3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/spectrum/sales_partition/saledate=2008-03/';

--Query using partition column `saledate`
SELECT TOP 5 
       spectrum.sales_part.eventid
     , SUM(spectrum.sales_part.pricepaid)
FROM spectrum.sales_part, event
WHERE spectrum.sales_part.eventid = event.eventid
  AND spectrum.sales_part.pricepaid > 30
  AND saledate = '2008-01'
GROUP BY spectrum.sales_part.eventid
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```